# MySql query syntax issue within prepared statement with regexp + concat

Tags: php, mysql, regex, prepared-statement, concatenation

I am revisiting my old fashion mysql related codes and converting them to prepared statement forms.
The query below was working properly.

```
$sorgu = "SELECT * FROM tb_yazilar WHERE kolon_etiketler REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$adres_get_elemanlari[2]."[[:>:]]' ORDER BY kolon_sno DESC";
```

### After update for prepared statement, my whole code is

```
$sorgum = "SELECT kolon_yazar, kolon_baslik, kolon_ytarihi FROM tb_yazilar WHERE kolon_etiketler REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]"', ?, '"[[:>:]]') AND kolon_statu = ? ORDER by kolon_onaytarihi DESC";

if ($beyan = $db_baglanti->prepare($sorgum)) 
{
    /* bind parameters */
    $beyan -> bind_param("ss", $bindparametre1, $bindparametre2);

    /* assign values to bind parameters */
    $bindparametre1 = tire_bosluk_olsun($_GET['rd_ozne']);
    $bindparametre2 = 'onay';

    /* execute statement */
    $beyan->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $beyan->bind_result($yazar, $baslik, $ytarihi);

echo "\t".'<div class="sol-icerik-kapsar">'."\r\n";
echo "\t\t".'<h1>'.$_GET['rd_ozne'].'İLE ETİKETLENDİRİLMİŞ YAZI(LAR)</h1>'."\r\n";
echo "\t\t".'<ul>'."\r\n";
    /* fetch values */
    while ($beyan->fetch()) 
    {
        echo "\t\t\t".'<li>'.'<a href="'.sitenin_koku.'yazılar/'.bosluklar_tire_olsun($yazar).'/'.bosluklar_tire_olsun(noktalamasiz($baslik)).'">'.$baslik.'</a>'.' - '.turkcetarih('j F Y',$ytarihi).'</li>'."\r\n";
    }
echo "\t\t".'</ul>'."\r\n";
echo "\t".'</div>'."\r\n";  
    /* close statement */
    $beyan->close();
}
else {echo "Hazırlama hatası: (" . $db_baglanti->errno . ") " . $db_baglanti->error;}
```

### Error message

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '', ?, '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in ... on line 2
I require your kind help since I couldn't solve my case with even stack-overflowing or googleing.
Thanks
BR

Comment: $sorgum = "SELECT kolon_yazar, kolon_baslik, kolon_ytarihi FROM tb_yazilar WHERE kolon_etiketler REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]"', ?, '"[[:>:]]') AND kolon_statu = ? ORDER by kolon_onaytarihi DESC";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A syntax-highlighting text editor would help you out here.

You have `"` nested inside `"`. They need to be escaped like `\"`.

```
$sorgum = "SELECT kolon_yazar, kolon_baslik, kolon_ytarihi FROM tb_yazilar WHERE kolon_etiketler REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]\"', ?, '\"[[:>:]]') AND kolon_statu = ? ORDER by kolon_onaytarihi DESC";
```

Comment: my syntax error has gone but now I can't have any value from my MySql table. Also there is no notice, warning or error. What should I do to understand the reason of NO DATA from mysql? I am sure that assigned values to bind parameters are correct & exist in my related table. BR

Comment: Check your mysql query log to see exactly what was run. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: thank you but I couldn't understand after reading the link you shared. I am on a free server and MySql version 5.1.61.

Comment: If you can use something like phpmyadmin, then you can run `show processlist` while your statement is executing, and that should show the full resulting query.